# Make sure both threads finish execution before executing a piece of code

Tags: android

I need to execute a piece of code when two conditions have been met.

1. Subject text is successfully queried from the database using background thread.
2. The dimension of View is retrieved successfully using main thread.
   Both Subject text and dimension of View are stored as Activity's member variable.

For 1), I simply start an AsyncTask in Activity's onCreate() and in doInBackground I query DB to get Subject text and store it in Activity's member variable.

For 2), I posted a Runnable to the UI thread, and in run(), I query view's dimension and store it in Activity's member variable. Done in onCreate() also.

It is not possible to guarantee which one (1 or 2) will finish first.

Therefore my question is, what is the recommended pattern to wait for both 1 and 2 to finish
before executing a piece of code?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [CountDownLatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

It is aimed to solve such problems.

First you need to create a latch somewhere in your code, Somewhere before 1) and 2)

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2); // wait for 2 threads;
```

In each of your actions, when it is complete, call a `countDown` on `latch` instance

```
latch.countDown();
```

In some point, where both of your threads must be complete, call `await` on `latch` instance

```
latch.await(); // Will block. Will resume after both thread are completed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think When you accomplish your first task using Async in its onPostExecute (as it will be called when your first task will be finished ) you can post runnable on UI thread or simply get view's measure dimension directly and then execute your piece of code you want .

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done it before is very simple. I just set a boolean value when the thread has finished. I then call a method from each thread to check that both values are true. Something a little like this:

```
onPostExecute(){

    queryComplete = true;

    checkThreadCompleted();

}


onPostExecute(){

    viewMeasured = true;

    checkThreadCompleted();

}

private void checkThreadCompleted(){

     if(queryComplete && viewMeasured){
         //Do something
     }
}
```

Comment: While this code works, you should not use it if "//Do something" must only run once. There is a small chance that the first thread will run queryComplete = true, and then be interrupted by the second thread. The second thread then runs viewMeasured = true, and continues with checkThreadCompleted where both variables are true. When the processor then jumps back to the first thread it will also run checkThreadCompleted where both variables are true.

Comment: That's a good point I hadn't considered. You could either set the variables in a synchronized method, or add another variable to check that it only runs once.